# boot classpath first directory value never changes after changing project JVM

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-7

I am running the "mavenproject1" project generated with "File::New Project::maven::JavaFx Application"  I am using Java 7 and 8 on Windows 7 with Netbeans 7.4.  My source code editor has had a problem finding the JavaFX packages when using Java 7.  My problem was solved by using Java 8, but I discovered something with the Boot Classpath when using Java 7 and 8 that seems like a bug.

I have noticed that my Boot Classpath for the source code related to "mavenproject1" has a static first entry that does not change when I change the target JVM.  When I put the jfxrt.jar into this static directory, my editor and my Maven project finds the JavaFX packages (with Java 7) and I can build and run the project with no errors.  Just curious where this entry came from? Is it a NB bug or does it correspond to some project parameter I set and forgot about?  Here's a partial list of my Boot Classpath from the source files using the Java 7 and 8:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar; <-Static path using JVM 1.7.0_45
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar; 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar; 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jsse.jar;
....

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar; <-Static path using JVM 1.8.0
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\resources.jar;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\rt.jar;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jsse.jar;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jce.jar;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\charsets.jar;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jfr.jar;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\classes;
....
```

Comment: Does your java 8 jre\lib folder contain jfxrt.jar?  If not, there's your answer.

Comment: Yes and that's why java 8 compiles and runs without a problem despite having this anomaly in the Boot Classpath.  My question is where does this path come from? .  Does it come from a Classpath environment variable?  Why does it persist after changing the JVM for the project?